# Rails rearranging orders in checklist model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am having a checklist model in rails with following columns.

```
product_id:int | content:string | archived:boolean | done:boolean
```

and i am currently listing those checklists in views normally like

```
<ul>
    <%=  @checklists.each do |list| %>
       <li><%= list.content %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Now i want to let users rearrange checklists orders like in [todoist](http://todoist.com).

How can i do that in rails? Do i have to do a migration to the database with additional columns like `order:int`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try add additional field like `list_index`
Then in `before create` callback in the model you can:

```
def set_index
  list_index = self.class.last_index + 1
end

def self.last_index
  self.order(list_index: :desc).first.list_index
end
```

Then on change position:

```
def change(current_index)
  self.class.where(self.class.arel_table[:list_index].gte(current_index)).update_all('list_index = list_index + 1')
  self.update(list_index: current_index)
end
```

You can move the selection of elements with a higher index to the scope:

```
scope :after_index, ->(current_index) { where(self.arel_table[:list_index].gte(current_index)) }
```